# Clarification of using [L] in htaccess rewrites?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wonder if you could just clarify a simple point for me please. Sorry if its a bit basic or been asked before. Ok say I have something like the following Rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^directory/file http://www.mysite.com/newdirectory/file [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/file2 http://www.mysite.com/newdirectory/file2 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^directory/file3 http://www.mysite.com/newdirectory/file3 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Since these changes are permanent, I'm using the R=301 flag. Now I am assuming I am correct in adding a [L] flag to each of these, since they are independent/separate rewrites and don't relate to each other? Now if I have a section underneath that deals with hotlinking, or some other rewrites, I'm assuming they will still work? I guess what I am trying to say is by using the [L] it doesn't stop all processing or Rewrite rules?

Again sorry if this is a stupid question, I just need someone to clarify it for me as I've read some articles about this, but in my mind they haven't made it 100% clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not a silly question and many web developers have misunderstanding around flag `L`.

This flag only stops current loop of rewrite (works like continue in a for loop) and forces rewrite engine to process rewrite rules again. It doesn't and cannot stop rules below or above to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. It does meant to stop processing the rules, but it doesn't stop the other rules.

The [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) docs says:

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed. This corresponds to the last command in Perl, or the break command in C. Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.

But, what it doesn't say is that:
(from [mediacollege](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/last.html))

> The L flag will tell Apache to stop processing the rewrite rules for
>   that request. Now what is often unrealised is that it now makes a new
>   request for the new, rewritten filename and begin processing the
>   rewrite rules again.
>
> Therefore, if you were to do a rewrite where the destination is still
>   a match to the pattern, it will not behave as desired. In these cases,
>   you should use a RewriteCond to exlude a certain file from the rule.